# Visual Studio Property not showing all Enum options

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, enums

I made a UserControl that has a Property of type `RotateFlipType`, this control is used within another UserControl that sets the property accordingly.

The thing is that according to [RotateFlipType MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.rotatefliptype.aspx) the Enum has 16 fields but VS Property Window only shows 14, `Rotate180FlipNone` and `RotateNoneFlipX` are missing.

I need to use `Rotate180FlipNone`. Setting it through the code works fine, but I really wouldn't wanna do it like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a closer look at the values in the combo box.  Note that it contains *duplicates*:

[image]

And yes, values are missing because of that.  The list still contains 16 values.

The reason for this is that the enum values for RotateFlipType are *ambiguous*.  There are only 8 distinct values.  Like RotateNoneFlipNone is the exact same transformation as Rotate180FlipXY.  Try it with a piece of paper.  Or intuitively, there are 4 possible rotations multiplied by 2 possible projections (original and flipped).   So what goes wrong is the type converter translating from the integral value of the enum (between 0 and 7) back to a string.  There are two to choose from and it just picks the first match.

You'll need to write your own TypeConverter to map a value to a different string, one of 8 possible strings.  You may want to write a UITypeConverter so it is a bit more obvious with, say, a bitmap that shows the transformation.